# Identify a Justice League character that can control glass

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

I vaguely remember sporadically watching episodes of the *Justice League* cartoon in the early to mid 2000s. And I think in one of the episodes I watched, I vaguely remember seeing a female character (possibly a villain?) who was able to take control of the shattered glass around her and turn the glass into her armor and weapon <strike>(possibly an axe?)</strike>. <strike>The scene where this occurred was possibly in outer space.</strike>

UPDATE: After reading the comment from @Blaze, it's apparent to me that I've remembered the details of the scene and character wrong. The stuff I remembered as shattered glass was actually metal chips. The scene did not take place in outer space. And the weapon created wasn't an axe.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I could remember all the villains from the _Justice League_ animated series from 2001-2004 but that doesn't ring any bell. Do you remember anything else by any chance?

Comment: The only character I know of which has glass as a theme is [Mirror Master](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_Master), but that doesn't seem to fit the description.

Comment: The scene you describe resonates to me as Queen of the Royal Flush Gang in “Wild Cards”. The battle is in a casino on the Las Vegas strip. The casino apparently uses metal chips as Queen sends a blizzard of them after Flash. When that fails, there are a clutter of the chips at her feet. She uses her metal TK to mold the disks into a form-fitting suit of armour and a big mace. Just in time to meet Hawkgirl’s mace

Comment: @Blaze I found some footage of the episode online, and after watching it I think you're right. It appears that I remembered numerous details of the scene and character wrongly.

Comment: Considering that the premise of the question was mistaken to begin with, "character that can control glass". I'm wondering if I should edit the title of the question to match the answer?

Comment: Nah, just leave the question as is, and you can accept @Blaze's answer once it's posted.

Comment: That being said, since you already edited the question, I'd say you can keep it as is too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scene you describe resonates with me as one involving the super villain [Queen](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Queen_(metahuman)) of the [Royal Flush Gang](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Royal_Flush_Gang#Joker%27s_Royal_Flush_Gang).  The moment took place in the *Justice League* adventure [*Wild Cards*](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Wild_Cards) (battling the fiendish game of the Joker), with the battleground being the casinos on the Las Vegas strip.

Queen's power is magnetic-metal telekinesis. One casino apparently used metal chips because she sweeps up a blizzard of them to assault the Flash. When that fails, there is a clutter of the metal chips at her feet. She uses her metal TK to mold the disks into a form-fitting suit of armour, with enough leftover to make a big mace.  Which she then uses to defend herself from Hawkgirl's mace:

Comment: It looks like she was fighting against GL instead of Flash, although the Yotuube video I found has so many cuts that we might be missing on some of the fights.

Comment: @Clockwork Cheers for that. Yeah, I couldn't find a decent clip of the moment. And I'm working off memory. I'm on holiday and my Justice League cartoon collection is back home. I think you may be right about Green Lantern. My recollections had Flash being chased by a swarm of coins and junk, but it may be crossed wires.